# Почему не работает связка ISC DHCP Server & Relay?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, debian, dhcp

Всем привет.

Такая проблема: есть 3 маршрутизатора на Linux: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первом работает DHCP сервер, второй Main GW служит главным шлюзом, форвардинг работает, и третий - CLI GW, на нем работает DHCP Relay.
Клиенты, подключенные к CLI-GW должны получать адреса из пула в первом маршрутизаторе, но почему то получения не происходит. Конфиги прилагаются.

dhcpd.conf: https://pastebin.com/5RPPw4T1

isc-dhcp-server:

INTERFACES="eth0 eth1"

Relay запускается командой: dhcrelay -a -i ens4 -i eth0 -d 172.16.50.2.

(где ens4 - интерфейс, смотрящий на клиентов CLI-GW, eth0 - на DHCP сервер).

На Main-GW пробовал делать маскарадинг между интерфейсами:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE;

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE.

Пакет на интерфейсе eth0 DHCP-сервера ловится, опция 82 присутствует, но лишь с одной суб-опцией - Circuit-ID = ens4. Как подключить Remote-ID - понятия не имею.

В общем, не знаю, куда уже копать. Есть мысль пересобрать isc-dhcp-server, но это я думаю, бред. На WorldSkills давали такое задание, и чувствую, там бы не стали собирать специальный пакет для такой задачи.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: для начала я бы убрал опцию `-i eth0`, а затем смотрел бы, как проходят пакеты через все точки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Так делалось уже. Пакеты DHCP Discover идут одинаково от интерфейса eth0 CLI-GW, до интерфейса eth0 сервера DHCP.

Comment: а ответы докуда доходят?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Доходит только запрос до интерфейса eth DHCP-сервера. Сам же сервер никак не отвечает, хоть в сервере и прописано условие на agent.circuit-id.

Comment: а если клиентский компьютер подключить вместо cligw, то ответ dhcp-сервер посылает? если да, 1. сравните поступающие запросы. 2. смотрите логи dhcp-сервера (вероятно, потребуется добавить ему «разговорчивости» — verbosity).